# MeteorJs: Return data Iron:router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Iron router return data is in template but I can't use it.

For example I have db with jobs, where every job has a `position` (e.g. `jobs.position`):

```
ExistJobPostController = RouteController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: 'existJob',
  data:function() {return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
})
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('existJob', {    
    path: '/jobs/:_id',
    controller: ExistJobPostController,
  });
});
<template name="existJob">      
  {{position}}
</template>
```

And nothing happens, I think that it's my fault, but I really can't understand how to fix this.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check that the correct data is even being set on your template data context. Here's a quick general summary of how to set the data context and how to access it from various locations:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {    
    path: '/index',
    data: function(){
      var obj = {
        fname: "Tom",
        lname: "Smith"
      };
      return obj;
    }
  });
});

Template.index.onRendered(function(){
  console.log(this.data.fname);
});

Template.index.events({
  'click body': function(e, tmpl){
    console.log(tmpl.data.fname);
  }
});

Template.index.helpers({
  lastName: function(){
    return this.lname;
  }
});

<template name="index">

  You have to use `this` when directly accessing template data from spacebars.
  {{this.firstName}}

  The following comes from Template.index.helpers:
  {{lastName}}

</template>
```